# SimpleSAML_php authentication from 8.x-3.0 to 8.x-3.2 results in error

Tags: 8

I updated SimpleSAML_php authentication from 8.x-3.0 to 8.x-3.2.

Since then, whenever I click on the SSO login button, I get this error.

> Exception: Could not resolve 'saml:SP': no class named 'sspmod_saml_Auth\Source_SP' or 'SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP'. in SimpleSAML\Module::resolveClass() (line 194 of /var/www/html/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Module.php).

I searched, but I couldn't find any information on it.

Everything is already set up (configurations, entityID in authsourse.php), but I still get this error.

Comment: Did you update it with dependencies? (composer update drupal/simplesamlphp_auth --no-dev -o --with-dependencies)?

Comment: Yes.I used this command- "composer require 'drupal/simplesamlphp_auth:^3.2'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

There was conflict because old version of simplesaml was present in custom folder, but when i updated via composer, new version got saved in contrib folder.

Answer (score 0):

We've encountered the same issue today while upgrading Drupal 8 to 9 and upgrading the simplesaml_php module to 3.2, using composer.

Solved by removing the entire simplesaml folder from the vendor folder `rm -rf vendor/simplesaml` and reinstalled again with `composer install`.